# Words with a property that is contradictory to their meaning

Tags: lists, contradiction

I've always been amused by words like "monosyllabic" which are self-contradictory in the sense that the word itself is not, in fact, one syllable. "Palindrome" is another example.  (Palindrome, contrary to its definition, does not read the same forwards and backwards.)

At one point I remember having at least two other similar examples, which I can no longer recall.

Is there a specific term for words that are themselves a counterexample of the concept they represent and are there other such words?

Comment: There are lots of examples: unpronounceable, meaningless, verb.

Comment: All the parts of speech, except '_noun_', are counterexamples of the concept they represent. '_Adjective_' is not an adjective, '_preposition_' is not a preposition, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Wikipedia...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autological_word)

> *An **autological** word (also called **homological** word or **autonym**) is a word that expresses a property that it also possesses (e.g. the word "short" is short, "noun" is a noun, "English" is English, "pentasyllabic" has five syllables, "word" is a word, "sesquipedalian" is a long word.*

The logical negating prefix should be ***an-***, leading to [***anautological***](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=%22anautological%22&aq=f&aqi=g5g-z1g4&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&gws_rd=ssl), but as you'll see from that link, Google says *no-one* has ever used that term. According to Wikipedia though, the opposite of ***autological*** is...

> [***heterological***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autological_word) *(e.g. "long" is not long, "verb" is not typically a verb, "monosyllabic" has five syllables, "German" is not German, etc.)*